# Checkboxes instead of icons in Accordion?

Tags: jquery-ui

In [jQuery UI's Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default), is it possible to have a checkbox instead of the icon?

Comment: So do you mean that checking the checkbox should show/hide the content ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8jm5t/)?

---

```
  $(function () {
      $("#accordion").accordion();
  });

  $(".ui-accordion-header-icon").each(function (index) {
      $(this).replaceWith('<input type="checkbox" name="xpto" value="' + index + '">')
  });

  $('#accordion input[type="checkbox"]').click(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

[<kbd><sub>**replacewith**</sub></kbd>](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

[<kbd><sub>**stoppropagation**</sub></kbd>](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)